# why is there three of these [0][0][0][0][0][0] when i console.log matrix?

Tags: javascript, console.log, nested-for-loop

ok, so I just want a simple explanation about why are there three [0][0][0][0][0][0] in my console inside a bigger array and not just one? my problem might be with nested for loops so if you guys could explain exactly what's happening here I would greatly appreciate it.

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Move let row = ... one line down, to the inside of the loop.

Comment: What you aren't realizing is you only have one sub array and are pushing references of that same array multiple times into the outer array. Try `matrix[0][0] = 1` and will see all sub arrays get that value because they are actually instances of the same array object

Comment: Hi, how is my answer going?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same `row` array all the time. Just create a new `row` array on each loop.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    let row = []; // Create the row inside the loop, so on each iteration a new row is created
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good use case for using Array.from() and its internal mapping callback and new Array constructor along with `Array#fill()`

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  return Array.from({length: m}, () => new Array(n).fill(0))
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Good answer but I think that the OP is not learning anything from this.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález That seems like a silly statement for several reasons. First, SO answers are for the long term knowledge base, not specifically for the OP only. Second, even if they don't quite follow how this approach works exactly they can read the docs for more understanding and often just knowing about simpler approaches helps you along the learning curve even if you aren't prepared to use them immediately

Comment: I was just stating that, *at least*, explain why he is failing, as the question and the content of the question is asking.